# Search as many of the conditions as possible on an entity in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Assume I have a SQL Server table with the following columns:

```
ID_PK uniqueidentifier NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
ID uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
TYPE int NOT NULL,
VALUE nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL
```

Further assume ID-TYPE combination and ID-TYPE-VALUE combination are unique across the database. TYPE can be 1, 2, or 3. Assume my data looks like this:

```
UI1 1 'A' 
UI1 2 'B'
UI2 1 'X'
UI2 3 'C'
UI3 2 'Y'
UI4 2 'B'
```

I need to search all of the TYPEs if they exist and where type 1 is 'A', type 2 is 'B', and type 3 is 'C'. If a type doesn't exist for a specific ID, then I don't need to search it. If a type has an incorrect value, then don't select the ID.

So, my result set should be like so:

```
UI1 1 'A'
UI1 2 'B'
UI4 2 'B'
```

UI2's type 1 is not 'A', so don't return UI2. UI3's type 2 is not 'B', so ignore this as well.

I then need the unique IDs:

```
UI1
UI4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT ID, TYPE, VALUE
FROM Table
WHERE (TYPE = 1 AND VALUE = 'A')
  OR (TYPE = 2 AND VALUE = 'B')
  OR (TYPE = 3 AND VALUE = 'C')
```

UPDATE:

```
SELECT t.ID
FROM t
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ID, MIN(CASE WHEN((TYPE = 1 AND VALUE = 'A')
    OR (TYPE = 2 AND VALUE = 'B')
    OR (TYPE = 3 AND VALUE = 'C')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS VALID
  FROM t 
  GROUP BY t.ID
) x 
ON x.ID = t.ID AND x.VALID = 1
GROUP BY t.ID
```

Comment: This does not work because it will return UI2 even though it's type 1 is 'X'.